# Ethernet setup on a pi similar device

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I want to connect a PLC : `192.168.8.100` to linux-Box that's similar to pi3 device:
I've set on both Ethernet ports a fix ip address, and the result of `ifconfig` is as  followed:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:FE:48:3A:55:AB
          inet addr:192.168.8.166  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76fe:48ff:fe3a:55ab%4804152/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:460 (460.0 B)  TX bytes:6745 (6.5 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:FE:48:3A:55:AC
          inet addr:192.168.8.167  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76fe:48ff:fe3a:55ac%4804152/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10120 (9.8 KiB)  TX bytes:34920 (34.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1%4804152/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:13288 (12.9 KiB)  TX bytes:13288 (12.9 KiB)
```

can one tell why I'm not eable to even ping the device when it's connected when it's pluged-in ? [ use the router, it works fine].

**Update**
[image]

thanks in advance !

Comment: You have the same subnet 192.168.8.*/24 on both network interfaces. This is not going to work, not even if both network interfaces are actually connected to the same switch. Please edit your question and tell us *why* you need such a configuration, *how* the rest of your network looks like and *what* do you want to achieve. (Also read up on [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), this very much looks like one).

Comment: @dirkt thanks for your reply. there is no network I just want to access the PLC through this linux box  ! and this while the PLC is connected directly to it, without router !

Comment: @dirkt I've added a picture to show what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Pi-like device is connected to a router on the first interface and you want to connect another device "PLC" on the second interface, just make sure you are using a different subnet.

(The rule of thumb when designing a network is to draw all subnets first (all devices connected via switches), and then give them an IP range, then draw devices connected to the subnets, and then think about routing etc. Don't think device-centric, think subnet-centric).

For example in your case, use `192.168.1.*/24` for the subnet between the Pi-like device and the "PLC", give `eth0` the static address `192.168.1.1`, and `PLC` the address `192.168.1.2`.

In general for such constructions, it helps to run a DHCP server on the Pi-like device, then "PLC" can get a dynamic address (and other information) from the Pi-like device automatically.

Note that in this configuration the "PLC" won't be able to access the router. There are various ways to allow this. The most common are to either enable IP forwarding on the Pi-like device and turn it into a router, possibly additionally with NAT, or to bridge both interfaces and turn the Pi-like device into a switch.

Which method is best depends on the circumstances.